# Symfony4 - MakerBundle : How to find all users by role?

Tags: symfony4

I would like to get all the admins among the users (ie having the role ROLE_ADMIN).

The attribute role is "json", so I think I can't use "like" or "=" operators.

I implemented user management using MakerBundle in symfony4 project (make:user then make:auth commands).

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];
}

class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findByRole($role){
        return  $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where("u.roles like :role  ")
            ->setParameter('role', '%'.$role.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function edit(UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $admins = $userRepository->findByRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
        dump($admins);
        exit;
    }
}
```

When I call the `findByRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` in a controller, the error message is :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERREUR: l'opérateur n'existe pas : json ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...AS reset_token_5 FROM itibr_user i0_ WHERE i0_.roles LIKE $1
```

I also tried to use scienta/doctrine-json-functions (https://packagist.org/packages/scienta/doctrine-json-functions), but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is based on https://www.remipoignon.fr/symfony-comment-verifier-le-role-dun-utilisateur-en-respectant-la-hierarchie-des-roles/ (sorry, it's a French article)

I created a GrantedService and then in my controller :

```
public function edit(UserRepository $userRepository){
        foreach($userRepository->findAll() as $user){
            if( $grantedService->isGranted($user, 'ROLE_ADMIN') ){
                //do something...
            }
        }
}
```

For my current project with very few users, it's OK. But I have other projects with thousands of users, I know that findAll() then test all is not a good practice. So I will have to fix this problem later on